# How to check if one application can access other application?

Tags: java, android

Several apps can launch other applications as well. For example from contacts we can launch Camera, Music, Message etc.

I have to track these interfaces. Any idea would be a great help.

What I have already done till now.

1. Check the permissions in the manifest file. I got all the packages installed on phone and then got all the permissions it has.
2. Check all the 'uses feature' in the manifest file.

The problem is the list is still not complete because most of the apps interact with other apps using intents. For example message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do this. An App interact with another, in most cases it use Intent. Just like when you want to take a photo by using a Camera or select a picture through a Gallery, codes may be like this:

Take a photo by a Camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                .getExternalStorageDirectory(),"temp.jpg")));
startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_GRAPH);
```

Pick a picture through a Gallery:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, null);
intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, IMAGE_UNSPECIFIED);
startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_ZOOM);
```

So, if you want to trace these interfaces, you need to detective Intents but not their `AndroidManifest.xml`.